# DataView boolean cell

Tags: c#, list, drop-down-menu, boolean, dataview

How would I add a cell to a DataView that was toggleable between True and False like the dataview in the Microsoft Visual C# properties window? I can only find a way to add a text box type cell to it, but I need to add a toggleable one, and also a dropdown list type. Thanks for any help.

Comment: A dropdown list boolean? So you mean a dropdown list containing 'True' and 'False'?

Comment: Like this: http://imgkk.com/i/8ub-.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you mean the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx). If [that's the case](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FilteredPropertyGrid/FilteredPropertyGrid.jpg), it's [as simple as handing it a class with a boolean property](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PropertyGridInCSharp11302005004139AM/PropertyGridInCSharp.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. I was using a DataView but PropertyGrid is far better, thanks.